# How to manipulate list position with javascript

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

am extending the bootstrap carousel plugin to allow me use image as thumbnail navigators. I have done this but the issue is how to show active list (thumbnail)

css:

```
.carousel-wrap {
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 408px;    
}
.carousel-indicators {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1000em
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider1" class="carousel-wrap">
                 <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-gallery">
                   <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive"></li>
                   <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=two" class="img-responsive"></li>
                   <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive"></li>
                   <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive"></li>
                   <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive"></li>
                 </ol>
             </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What excactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to show the rest list items when next or previous button is clicked..something similar to this ( http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caro-pager.php) but it should be an infinite carousel

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#slider1 li').on('click', function(){
// remove class 'active' from all li
$("#slider1 li").removeClass("active");
// add class 'active' to the clicked li
$(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

Put this JavaScript before the slider-HTML and style the list elements with css depending on the .active class.